# Binding Datasets to Parameter

Tags: reporting-services

Please can someone tell me how to bind a dataset to parameters (@Productcategory and @PriceRange) that uses this filtering condition or is there another way to have written this filter.

Thanks Emma

```
WHERE ( ( ProductCategory.Name = @ProductCategory OR
          ( @ProductCategory = 'All Bike Related' AND 
            ProductCategory.Name IN ('Bikes', 'Components')) OR
          (@ProductCategory ='All')
        ) AND
        ( (@PriceRange = 'Less than 50' AND ListPrice < 50) OR
          (@PriceRange ='50 to 99' AND ListPrice BETWEEN 50 AND 99) OR
          (@PriceRange ='100 to 499' AND ListPrice BETWEEN 100 AND 499) OR
          (@PriceRange ='500 and higher 'AND ListPrice >=500) OR
          (@PriceRange = 'All')
        )
      )
```

Answer (score 0):

If you create your report from scratch with the query including the WHERE clause as provided (assuming you are querying a SQLServer datasource), then you should find that the parameters ProductCategory and PriceRange are generated and bound to your query dataset automatically.

However, to add the parameters manually (assuming the query already includes these conditions):

- In the Report Data window:

  - For each parameter right-click on the Parameters node and select `Add Parameter...` . Specify the name and available/default values as required.
  - Expand the Datasets node, right-click on the dataset that the parameters are to be bound to, and select `Dataset Properties`.

    - Select the Parameters option in the `Dataset Properties` dialog, then add each parameter name from your query and match it to the appropriate report parameter (as set up in the previous step).
    - Click OK at the bottom of the `Dataset Properties` dialog to confirm the changes.

(Note: this assumes SSRS 2008 R2 - the dialogs involved may be slightly different in other versions of SSRS.)